# How to connect a removable multipolar signal flat cable to PCB

Tags: pcb-design, pcb-assembly

Wich is the best and easy way to connect this kind of cable to a PCB in a manner that it can be attached or removed to and from the PCB?

[image]

Comment: That's called a ribbon cable, they were used extensively for data inside computers in the 80s through 00s (largely replaced by serial protocols with smaller cables now though), so you should be able to find lots of solutions if you look for ribbon cable connectors.

Answer (score 2):

Look for "rectangular board to wire insulation displacement connectors (IDC)." Measure the distance from wire-to-wire (the pitch) and look for connectors that match and have the same number of conductors/pins.

Something like this [Adam Tech FTR-10-T](https://app.adam-tech.com/products/download/data_sheet/203419/ftr-xx-t-data-sheet.pdf) could work, but it depends on what your other requirements are.

[image: Adam Tech FTR-10-T]

Comment: This is the easiest, but with a small number of connections and some care you can use a molex kk - that uses a single row header